# How to display fetched array from api in CSelect element in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I want to display list of provinces in select element .I have fetched data from api but I can't display it in select element...I have seen alot about React-Select on the internet But I use CSelect element...This is my code....What's wrong?

```
const RequestAgency = (props) => {
let provinces = [];
  function renderProvinces(){
    
    UserService.getProvince().then(
      (response) => {
      
    provinces =response.data ;
  
    provinces.map(province=>{
      console.log(province.ItemName)
     return <option  value={province.ID}>{province.ItemName}</option>
    })
     }
    
    );

  }
 return (
<CFormGroup row>
 <CCol md="3">
    <CLabel htmlFor="province">  province</CLabel>
  </CCol>
  <CCol xs="12" md="9">
    <CSelect custom name="province" id="province" >
    {renderProvinces()}
    </CSelect>
  </CCol>
</CFormGroup>
)

}
export default RequestAgency
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always best practice to use `useState` react hook, to store data and render to page.

I'll suggest you to use the `useState` properly, and use `useEffect` to get the data from api.

Here I've use the `useState` to store data, `useEffect` to fetch data from api and use the `async/await` for asynchronous api call.

This code seems easy to understand and debugging.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const RequestAgency = (props) => {
  const [provinces, setProvinces] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const provinces = await UserService.getProvince()
      setProvinces(provinces.data)
    };
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <CFormGroup row>
      <CCol md="3">
        <CLabel htmlFor="province"> province</CLabel>
      </CCol>
      <CCol xs="12" md="9">
        <CSelect custom name="province" id="province">
          {provinces.map((province, i) => {
            return (
              <option key={i} value={province.ID}>
                {province.ItemName}
              </option>
            );
          })}
        </CSelect>
      </CCol>
    </CFormGroup>
  );
};

export default RequestAgency;
```